# Error trying to save Excel worksheet as CSV via Excel VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, csv, excel-2010

Using Excel 2010 on Windows 7. I have a VBA macro that saves the first worksheet of an excel workbook (.xlsm) into a CSV file. This had mostly worked in the past. Recently, I get error messages per the picture below, which state "Run-time error '1004': Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space."

So a couple things:

- A common suggested solution from my Google searching is to set the file's location as a Trusted Location. This did not work.
- I have enough disk space. That can't be the issue.
- I'm not sure exactly what is meant by "available memory," but if it in any way refers to the Physical Memory figure listed in Windows Task Manager, that figure is 75%. The ultimate CSV file itself tends to be about 1,500KB.
- I am always able to save this worksheet as a CSV manually without encountering any error messages, but when I do it via this VBA macro, I get the error message.

[Picture of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D51JA.png)

My excel VBA save-as-CSV macro:

```
Sub saveAsCSV()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="dummyfilename.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy` with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate`

Comment: I suspect that the error is caused by the absence of a path in your SaveAs instruction. Add a path to the file name and see if the error persists.

Comment: To clarify, I do have a path in my SaveAs instruction. I'm just using a dummy as I don't feel the need to use the actual path here, but I now understand how that's misleading.

Comment: On which drive do you save your file? And on which drive is AppData? In case these are different did you check both for free space?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you don't have to use `Copy` or `Activate`. If your code is in the workbook that you want to save as a workbook you can use `ThisWorkbook`. Kudos to @Variatus for identifying need for a path.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "dummyfilename" & ".csv", FileFormat:=6
```